# Background issues in Mobile Browser

Tags: css, html

I have a background image that covers the entire screen. It works like a charm in web. However when I click an input field in mobile browser, the background shifts (I believe so) and shows a white colour. Since my input fields are also white, I can't see them when things get messed up as such.

Attaching the screenshot of both states before clicking the input field and after clicking it as well on mobile.

CODE HERE:

```
<body class="details_step1-1">
   <div>
   ...........
   </div>
</body>
```

CSS HERE:

```
.details_step1-1{
    background-image: url("../images/img_foldbg.png");
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
}
```

TRIED FIXES: 
 1. Adding min-height to the background image, html, body as 100% together as well as separately.
 2. Adding height as 100vh to the background image, html and body.

[image: Before Clicking on Input Field]

[image: After Clicking on Input Field]

Comment: What kind of phone are you using? It almost looks like the keyboard is pushing up the .details_step1-1 div, which would explain why it still centers the background image when the keyboard is open. It seems like there is a clash of z-indexes going on there as well, which would explain why your input and "edit" link is showing up on top of the white space of the keyboard. Kind of tough to diagnose without having access to the site though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply overflow:auto on both your html tag and your body tag, and that will fix your white space issue.

Comment: Thanks.. will give this a try tomorrow and let you know. :)

Comment: Thanks man. solved my problem. You guys here at stack wow me.